# Picker view value did not change inside scroll view because it scrolls

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a pickerView inside a scrollview but when i change the value of picker view it gets scrolled and the value did not get changed.
Please tell me what I should do to prevent scrolling when it is on picker view.

Please help me
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add pickerView outside scrollView

Answer (score 1):

Apple's HIG refuse to put picker view inside a scrollable view. I recommend to put it in a popup view unless the scroll view in scrollable horizontally only.